# Why does Dependabot always have merge conflicts with lock file (pnpm-lock.yaml)?

Tags: javascript, github, dependency-management, github-dependabot

I have a monorepo which I manage with turborepo. I use Dependabot on GitHub to manage dependencies.

As far as I can tell, the Dependabot pull requests always have merge conflicts for the lock file (in my case *pnpm-lock.yaml*).

Why does that happen? I expected it to base the change on the main branch. Presumably, if the main branch is updated, the PR should also be updated.

How can I address it so lock file merge conflicts do not occur?

**Edit:**

From the [Dependabot docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#rebase-strategy):

> When rebase-strategy is set to auto, Dependabot attempts to rebase
> pull requests in the following cases:
>
> - When a Dependabot pull request is in conflict after a recent push to the target branch.

I have not set the `rebase-strategy` in *dependabot.yml*, as it is supposed to default to `auto`.

**Edit 2:**

I am using Dependabot alongside the changeset Github action that creates a new commit and PR with app version numbers updated, which I manually merge back onto main. Not sure if that is causing the issue.